# HUD,zeitgiest and the record activity toggle

Tags: hud

I am using Ubuntu 12 LTS. I was wondering if turning off the record activity toggle under the privacy menu effected the performance of the HUD? Also, does doe HUD use Zeitgiest? Does the Record activity toggle record to the Zeitgiest file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "record activity" toggle switches Zeitgeist on or off; if it's off Zeitgeist doesn't record anything (but any already recorded events are preserved).

The HUD doesn't use Zeitgeist so it's not affected by the "record activity" toggle.

Comment: Doesn't the HUD learn about your preferred commands using Zeitgeist?